# Auto-Layout vertical spacing issue

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm having some issues with auto-layout where it would show different spacing in IB than in runtime.

Here's the screenshot of IB:

[image: IB screehsot]

As you can see, the big numbers don't have any padding at the top and bottom.

But when run, it looks like this:

[image: runtime screenshot]

Am I missing something?

BTW, I come from Android dev, and looking at all those constraints I feel like I'm either missing a simpler solution or iOS UI dev is a real pain compared to Android.

Comment: The red arrow you can see in your IB screenshot means that you have conflicting constraints.  Click on the arrow and it will give you a list of which constraints are conflicting.

Comment: what happens if you increase the font size of the numbers?

Comment: @dan the red arrow is showing me content priority ambiguity

Comment: @f_qi oh, the numbers get "squeezed" into the same space...

Comment: @SimonReggiani could you upload a screenshot of the number label boarder? so when you click on the label, it shows dash line around the label.

Comment: @f_qi you mean this: http://imgur.com/a/j2Ubc ?

Comment: Can you screenshot the constraint error you're getting?

Comment: @SimonReggiani Yes.  As you can see, on top of the label, you are align the label's top boarder to the blue line.  You can actually align the top boarder to the top edge, above the blue line.  In auto-layout, when setting constants,  if you are using `standard` value, it's actually `=8`, if you click on the top and bottom constants, and change the value to `=0`, this might give you extra space and get rid of the padding.

Comment: @f_qi all the constraint constants are =0

Comment: @dstepan: http://imgur.com/a/I1mHT

Comment: @f_qi I'm talking about the "padding" inside the yellow box, not outside

Comment: The size that your view ends up being in your app is larger than the placeholder size you have set in IB, so some part of the view has to be stretched vertically to fit.  That's what the content priority ambiguity is warning you about: It wants you to explicitly define which views are allowed to be stretched.  Since you aren't resolving the ambiguity it decides itself to stretch your number labels.

Comment: What if I don't want to stretch anything? I want my cell to be as heigh as the height of the value and the height of the label (which I did by specifying all the constraints).

Comment: Whatever is adding that view as a subview is the thing that decides what size it is.  If the sizing view doesn't give constraints that explicitly decide your view's height then it will size itself to be the height of your two labels.

Comment: I'm using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` so that's what happens. But why is there more spacing between the numbers (e.g. `7`) and the labels (e.g. `people driven`) in runtime than in IB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"I'm either missing a simpler solution or iOS UI dev is a real pain compared to Android"*

You're missing a simpler solution. Auto-layout can be frustrating, until you get the hang of it. After that, it makes things sooooo much easier than it used to be.

Here is a version of your table cell, where the spacing stays consistent between IB and runtime. And, it uses `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

[image]

As you can see, it's much simpler than what you had. If you tell me if you're using Objective-C or Swift (2.2? 3.0?) Xcode 7 or 8, I'll be happy to make the files available...

Comment: Thanks DonMag. I started to use StackViews as well and came up with exactly the same stuff as you and was pretty happy about it, until Xcode told me I couldn't use StackViews as my iOS Deployment Target was 8.0 and not 9.0...

Comment: ah - I'll take another look in a bit... should be able to get you where you want to be.

Comment: Is it common to set the Deployment Target to 9? I see in my analytics that I still have 1% of devices using 8.4...

Comment: Here's *one* way to do it without Stack Views - https://github.com/DonMag/DynoCell84 As far as maintaining compatibility back to iOS 8, well... I'm sure you can find volumes of discussion about that. It's always going to be a balance between how much work to keep it versus loss of sales if you drop it.

Comment: Thanks Don! I ended up upgrading to 9.0